# How to debug custom metric values in tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have defined a very simple custom metric, in tf.keras, for tracking number of pixels predicted as '1' for a segmentation problem. Since the output from the last layer has sigmoid activation, I'm rounding **y_pred** and then summing. I expect to see a whole integer value (>= 0) (because of the rounding) but the output shows floating point numbers like 0.28. How is that possible? How can I debug this to figure out where the problem is?

I tried switching from **tf.keras.backend.sum** & **tf.keras.backend.round** to **tf.reduce_sum** & **tf.round** but that didnt solve the issue

```
def num_ones(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.backend.sum(tf.keras.backend.flatten(tf.keras.backend.round(y_pred)))

model.compile(optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy', num_ones])


output-
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 3408: accuracy = 0.9551756, global_step = 3408, loss = 0.7224839, num_ones = 0.28
```

Comment: What is your batch size? Your metric would be averaged through your batch?

Comment: My batch size is 8, I just want to see the counts of '1' pixels after rounding across the whole batch. I'll average it in the next step but just getting the counts is giving me incorrect values.

Answer (score 3):

Function

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

works fine with Tensorflow >2.3 but you have to define your custom metric function as tensorflow function (add the decorator):

```
@tf.function
def num_ones(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.backend.sum(tf.keras.backend.flatten(tf.keras.backend.round(y_pred)))
```

Comment: The tf.function decorator was crucial in my case. Thanks!

Comment: Verified. This should be an accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

To answer how you should debug the custom metrics, call the following function at the top of your python script:

```
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

This will force tensorflow to run all functions eagerly (including custom metrics) so you can then just set a breakpoint and check the values of everything like you would normally in your debugger.

Comment: It also works with `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` with TensorFlow-2.5.0.